# Azure AKS IP address to whitelist Image Registry

Tags: azure, azure-aks, amazon-ecr

Created AKS cluster in Azure, I have Image registry running in ECR, before downloading images from ECR I need to white list AKS public IP

How can I get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Azure Firewall to protect your AKS cluster. Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/protect-azure-kubernetes-service). Maybe you can try to use the ACR and give appropriate permission to the AKS, on my opinion it's better and safer.